Is it possible to edit the material of an object from a linked blend file?
A while ago I made a character in Blender

Just recently I added the custom bone shapes to it, but, when I append it to other projects I need to disable all of the bone shapes, which aren't a lot, but its still annoying.
The solution was using link instead of append, which worked. I didn«t need to disable the bone shapes anymore, but the problem is, that the face rig I used on the character, isn't really a face "rig".
I used image sequences and used that to change expressions, but when using link, I cant change the material of the face:

So I was wondering if its possible to change the material of an object from a linked blend file, if it isn't possible, then that's fine, I don't have to disable a lot of bone shapes, but I still hope its possible

Click on Object > Relations > Make Local > Selected Objects:

Then click on Material panel > Link > Object and you'll be able to give your object a new material:

If you want to edit the existing material, select it in the material list:

Click on New Material and edit this material:


It didnt work, it created a new material, i want to be able to edit the already existing one

I've edited my answer, does it answer?

It worked, thanks
